# Can I categorize pages and filter by said categories with Google's CSE API?

Tags: google-custom-search

The title sums it up but here's a hypothetical example:

I have a cooking sites that has 10000 pages; 3000 recipe pages, 3000 ingredient pages, 3000 pages of the messageboard and 1000 one-off static pages.  I wanted to add search to my site so I setup the CSE API and it has been working great.  Now on the search results page I would like to add a way for users to be able to filter what ether are searching for which would be "all pages", "recipe pages", "ingredient pages", "messageboard pages", "other pages".  Is setting up this filtering possible?  Keep in mind it is a site I own so I can either upload lists of pages and can also edit the markup on the HTML pages themselves.  Also keep in mind that all URLs are similar for each type, e.g. www.example.com/recipes/... begins all recipe pages, www.example.com/ingredient begins all ingredient pages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using refinement tabs: https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/70359?hl=en

In your case, you need refinements like 'recipe' and 'messageboard'. Once you create those, in your sites to search section you can add these patterns and associate them with appropriate labels:

www.example.com/recipe -> recipe labe
www.example.com/messageboard -> messageboard recipe

etc.

In the results page, these will appear as tabs on top. You can style them using Look and Feel section of control panel.

Comment: I'm using the API so there is no "results page"

Comment: Then the refinement information is in the api response - in JSON API e.g. under items[].labels[]: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list